# String '\' replace with '/'

Tags: python, string

```
a='C:/Users/me/Documents/PythonProjects/opencv/Train\11\00011_00014_00018.png'
```

I am running a for loop with variables such as a, that are strings.
I intend to obtain the number 11 from the string above.

Using `a.replace('\\,'/')` , i get the exact same string back , that is, `'C:/Users/me/Documents/PythonProjects/opencv/Train\11\00011_00014_00018.png'`

the only way i got it to work was with `r/'C:/Users/me/Documents/PythonProjects/opencv/Train\11\00011_00014_00018.png'.replace('\\','/')` but that does not work with variables i.e

```
r'a'.replace('\\','/')
```

its not like f-strings whereby i can parse variables as such f'{a}'

Comment: Use a double backslash, `\\ `, to indicate a (normal) backslash.

Comment: `replace` does not mutate the string inplace, probably you are not assigning it to itself after using `replace`.

Answer (score 3):

I would instead recommend using `os.path` if your intention is to clean up or mutate filesystem paths

```
>>> import os
>>> a='C:/Users/me/Documents/PythonProjects/opencv/Train\11\00011_00014_00018.png'
>>> os.path.normpath(a)
'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\PythonProjects\\opencv\\Train\t\x0011_00014_00018.png'
```

Using `os.path` for path manipulation will generally behave correctly on different operating systems without you having to manually modify slashes, drive names, etc.

Comment: You still mentioned the C drive, so I'm not sure I understand the point on drive names

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked !

root_dir = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/PythonProjects/opencv/Train'

all_img_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '**.png'))

for img_path in all_img_paths:

try:
        img = preprocess_img(io.imread(img_path))
        label = get_class(img_path)

to:

all_img_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.normpath(root_dir), '**.png'))
np.random.shuffle(all_img_paths)